# How to use impatient mode with external .css files linked in the .html file?

Tags: html, css, emacs

I have installed impatient-mode in emacs, and I would like to edit both the html file and the external css file linked in the  tag and see the changes automatically in the browser:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/my/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

The problem is that when I edit my css, nothing happens, and the html file which appears in the browser stops loading content.

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Just enable `impatient-mode` in the linked CSS file as well as the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct but Try to check your css file path first.

Comment: Yes, it is right, because it loads the css file properly, but when I edit it, changes are not applied automatically as in html with impatient mode.
Does it work in your emacs?